# Youtube-dl get JSON of the best format only

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to get information about the best format of the movie, but I don't want to download it, just get the information in JSON.

I tried to write

```
-f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4 --dump-json
```

But it brought up a list of all the formats, and I don't know which one is the best.

How can I get clean JSON with only the best format?